# how can you find the confidence level of the prediction in testing multiclass svm using scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

my code:

`clf=svm.NuSVC(probability=True)
clf.fit(X,Y)
print clf.predict_proba(test_image)`

how can i know which probability is for the predicted class. it gives me an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `predict_prob` method here returns an array of shape `(n_samples, n_classes)`. The columns correspond to the classes in sorted order, as they appear in the attribute classes_.

Comment: what do you mean by sorted here? can the classes be jumbled in the results for multi class ?